# PyOWM and weather alerts

Tags: python-3.x, api, openweathermap

I'm pretty new to Python programming.  I'm trying to figure out the PyOWM api and I've fumbled my way through it.  Biggest issue is trying to find all the class names and values using ONE_CALL.  I'm really stuck on weather alerts that are in the json string that is returned from open weather maps.  Reading the pyown docs I don't see any other reference other then to create your own alert tiggers.

With pyowm after calling one_call(lat,lon) it gets the response back from the server and you can go through and get specific items like temp and wind i.e.

```
print(one_call.current.temperature.get('temp'))
```

I have figured out how to get the hourly and daily forecasts.

Currently we are under a weather alert and it shows in the json that is returned but I don't know how to get pyowm to get that alert.  The one_call section of the PDF is very lacking in what it exposes.  Well at least to me that is.  Like I say I'm new to Python and it's been 15 years since I did any real programming.  Used to do VB6 and some C and C++ but that's about it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

since pyOWM is a wrapper for a much more complex API, it can be that maybe they haven't implemented the Alerts section of the Open Weather API.
I tried browsing through their documentation and even their codebase but there are no references to alters i could find.

I'd suggest to use the wrapper (as it is much simpler for anything not alert-related) and to request alerts separately, if that can be done in your use case.
So after checking the weather you could do something like:

```py
import requests

# this is what returns your weather data, with the given parameters. 
# note that we're excluding everything except alerts so that you only receive those
API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid={API key}".format(your_lat, your_lon, 'current,minutely,hourly,daily', your_api_key)

# we call the endpoint to get alert info only
alert_data = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT)

# now let's check the HTTP status to make sure everything went right:
if alert_data.status_code == 200:
    print(alert_data['alerts']
    # inside this variable there are all alerts
else:
    print('some %s error occurred' % alert_data.status_code)
```

alerts inside the alert_data variable will have **this** format, as per OWM specification, so it's a list of dictionaries:

```json
"alerts": [
    {
      "sender_name": "NWS Tulsa",
      "event": "Heat Advisory",
      "start": 1597341600,
      "end": 1597366800,
      "description": "...HEAT ADVISORY REMAINS IN EFFECT FROM 1 PM THIS AFTERNOON TO\n8 PM CDT THIS EVENING...\n* WHAT...Heat index values of 105 to 109 degrees expected.\n* WHERE...Creek, Okfuskee, Okmulgee, McIntosh, Pittsburg,\nLatimer, Pushmataha, and Choctaw Counties.\n* WHEN...From 1 PM to 8 PM CDT Thursday.\n* IMPACTS...The combination of hot temperatures and high\nhumidity will combine to create a dangerous situation in which\nheat illnesses are possible."
    },
    ...
  ]
```